# Push notifications on mobile apps

Tags: mobile, push-notification

OK, how do push notifications work?

I found a nice tutorial: http://lessons.runrev.com/m/4069/l/59312

I get the concept that the device needs to register with the server but does the app essentially hold an AJAX connection to server or does the server somehow plug into the mobile phone network... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three essential components when talking about push notifications:

1. Your server
2. The providers server
3. Your mobile device

Your server is the sender. It sends the push notification to the providers server, which in turn sends it to the device. Your device, therefore, is the receiver. (Concluding that you don't have to "plug into the mobile phone network", this is all done by your provider - Google in this case)
Within your mobile application you just register an eventhandler which is fired when you receive a push notification.

Google called this C2DM (Cloud to Device Messaging), now GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) - you can get an introduction inclusive of an architectural overview and demos [here at android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question I know:
Both push notifications services (Apple's and Microsoft's)  are using a persistent IP connection for implementing their push notifications functionality.

I think Android works the same way (at least with Android Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM)). "It uses an existing connection for Google services". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Cloud_to_Device_Messaging_Service

But the answer is closer to AJAX, except I assume it is a simple "http" connection to Google Messaging service from Android, and the OS gets an alert of a new message and relays it back to a program that registered on it to want notifications.